# How to add same animation nodes to multiple meshes?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

So I have a wiggle node animation and I have a couple meshes that I would like to use the same wiggle node tree.  How do I add the node tree to all the other meshes.

Also, how do I randomize them so they all don't wiggle the same way?

My node tree for the wiggle goes like this:

Time info ---> Vector Wiggle ---> Object Transform Output

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **Loop** lets you reuse a node tree for all items of a list of any type.

*Add* > *Subprograms* > *Loop* will place the *Loop Input* node. After you add a new iterator, probably an *Object List* in your case, you should be able to connect the *Loop Input* to your existing tree.

*Add* > *Subprograms* > *Invoke Subprogram* > *loop_name* then provides a node with the *Object List* input that you can feed with the output of a *Create Object List*, a *From Group* or a custom script.

The *Loop Input*'s **Index** connected to the **Seed** input of the *Vector Wiggle* (or any other node which generates random numbers) makes sure that different numbers for each iteration of the loop will be generated. This prevents your objects from moving in formation.

[image: basic wiggle]

If you want each object to individually wiggle around a different specified location, then you have the option to either add that location as a **second iterator** of type *Vector List*…

[image: vector list wiggle]

…or use the **Object ID Key** node to store and access the initial transformation values.
(Thanks to Jacques Lucke for [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60590/34236) which describes how to use this node.)

[image: object id key wiggle]